# Prove that $\det ((A + B + C) (A^3 + B^3 + C^3-3ABC))\geq 0 $

Tags: matrices, determinant, factoring

> Suppose that A, B and C are 2x2 matrices that switch between each
> other. Prove that
> $$\det ((A + B + C) (A^3 + B^3 + C^3-3ABC))\geq 0. $$

I did

$$A^3+B^3+C^3-3ABC=\frac12(A+B+C)((A-B)^2+(A-C)^2+(B-C)^2)$$

So, this determinant is equivalent to

$$\frac14[\det(A+B+C)]^2\det((A-B)^2+(A-C)^2+(B-C)^2)$$

But how can I prove that

$$\det((A-B)^2+(A-C)^2+(B-C)^2)\geq0?$$

Can someone help me? Thanks for attention.

Comment: What is the meaning of switch between each other?

Comment: I presume they should commute.

Comment: Michael Hoppe is right, @Dhanvi Sreenivasan .

Answer (score 3):

Based on Aryaman Maithani's idea:

Presumably the matrices are real. Let $X=A-B,\,Y=B-C$ and $Z=C-A$. Then $X,Y,Z$ commute and $X+Y+Z=0$. Let $\omega$ be a primitive cube root of unity. Then
\begin{aligned}
\det(X^2+Y^2+Z^2)
&=\det(X^2+Y^2+(-X-Y)^2)\\
&=4\det(X^2+Y^2+XY)\\
&=4\det\left[(X-\omega Y)(X-\bar{\omega}Y)\right]\\
&=4|\det(X-\omega Y)|^2\\
&\ge0.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Using $Z = -(X+Y)$, the expression of interest becomes $\det(X^2 + Y^2 + (X+Y)^2)$. Its sign is the same as that of $\det(X^2 + Y^2 + XY)$. Maybe that helps?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani It does, thanks.

Comment: Isn't that Z = A - C from the question while in answer it is Z=C - A)?