# Find values that k may take if $k=\det\left(A^3+B^3+C^3\right).\det\left(A+B+C\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A,B,C$ be $n\times n$ matrices with real entries such that their product is pairwise commutative. Also $ABC=O_{n}$. If
$$k=\det\left(A^3+B^3+C^3\right).\det\left(A+B+C\right)$$
then find the value or the range of values that $k$ may take.

**My Attempt**

I tried $k=\left(\det(A+B+C)\right)^2\left(\det(A^2+B^2+C^2-AB-BC-CA)\right)$. but couldn't go further than this

Comment: $O_n$ being? Zero?

Comment: Yes. Null matrix

Comment: Can you show that the right term is always non-negative? This then implies that $k$ is always non-negative, and so we just need to find matrices for any given $k$, and there's a pretty natural construction for that.

Comment: Closely related: [Prove that $\det((A+B+C)(A^3+B^3+C^3-3ABC))\geq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3738730).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k=det(A^3+B^3+C^3).det(A+B+C)$$=det(A^3+B^3+C^3-3ABC).det(A+B+C)$

$=det\{(A+B+C)(A+\omega B+\omega^2 C)(A+\omega^2 B+\omega C)\}.det(A+B+C)$

$=(det(A+B+C))^2det(A+\omega B+\omega^2 C)det(\overline{A+\omega B+\omega^2 C})$

$=(det(A+B+C))^2(X+iY)(X-iY)$

$=(det(A+B+C))^2(X^2+Y^2)$

$\geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Show that $\det (A^2 + B^2 + C^2 - AB - BC - CA ) \geq 0$. (See the linked problem.)
2. Show that $ k \geq 0 $.
3. For any $ k \geq 0$, find matrices $A, B, C$ that satisfy the condition.

Hints for the construction:

> Diagonal matrices work.

> The non-zero values are all the same, and equal to ...

> The condition $ABC = 0$ means ...

> If $ k > 0$, what does that imply about $A+B+C$?

Comment: Yes. But how to show  $\det (A^2 + B^2 + C^2 - AB - BC - CA ) \geq 0$

Comment: @Maverick I'm guessing you viewed it as $ M =  \frac{1}{2} ( (A-B)^2 + (B-C)^2 + (C-A)^2)$ already. Can you relate this is a positive semi-definite matrix?

Comment: @CalvinLin What is your definition of "positive semidefinite"? It is certainly not necessarily the case that $M$ is symmetric, which is typically part of the requirement

Comment: Yes. I did that but i haven't studied about this semi-positive definite matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah dang it. I only considered the $z^T M z \geq 0$ because of the sum of squares. I forgot we do need the symmetric part. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Maverick See the linked problem. That was the next step I was going to look into, to exploit the conditions of the problem.

Comment: I did try something like that but goofed up in between. Thanks